# TypeScript issue with find and filter

Tags: angular, typescript

```
let access = environment.access.filter(it => it.roleName === userRole);

let access = environment.access.find(it => it.roleName == userRole);
```

**Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{ siteadmin: string[]; manager: string[]; employee: string[]; contractor: any[]; }'.**

This should work but I can't figure out why it's throwing this error when i **ng build** or **ng serve**

using Angular 13

Environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl:"https://localhost:5001/api/",
  access: [{
    roleName:"siteadmin",
    access:['page1','home', 'usermanagement']
  },
  {
    roleName:"manager",
    access:['home']
  },
  {
    roleName:"employee",
    access:['page1','home']
  },
  {
    roleName:"contractor",
    access:['page1','home', 'usermanagement']
  }
],
};
```

access is an array of objects

Comment: What is `environment.access`?  The error suggests that it's not an array, but an object.  And `.filter()` is on arrays.

Comment: @David I added the information. environment is the environment.ts file and access is an array within it.

Comment: Is this a runtime error from JavaScript, or a build-time error from TypeScript or a linter?  Perhaps there’s an incorrect type definition somewhere, and it’s not actually expecting the type you’re providing.  Where is the type for environment.access defined?  Can your IDE’s intellisense and whatnot help find that?

Comment: build error from Terminal when I type ng serve or ng build. The IDE doesn't complain that there is any syntax issue @David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet the problem is that you've edited the environment.ts file, but you haven't updated the environment.prod.ts (or the equivalent for whatever configuration you've supplied with ng serve) file to match the same structure. Angular performs a file replacement as part of its build process that won't be caught by your editor's type checking.

Comment: You were right about that. I thought ng serve would use my non-production version of environment.ts and I suppose ng build would use my production version.